# When adding my Google account, how can I grant GNOME just some permissions?

Tags: online-accounts, google-calendar, gnome-calendar

I want to integrate my Google Calendar with the Calendar app in GNOME. To do that, I need to add Google to my Online Accounts, by launching Online Accounts in GNOME:

[image: Screenshot]

When I try to add my Google account, it asks for these permissions:

- Read, compose, send and permanently delete all your email from Gmail
- See, edit, create and delete all of your Google Drive files
- View, edit, delete and manage your Google Cloud Print printers and print jobs
- See, edit, download and permanently delete your contacts
- See, edit, share and permanently delete all the calendars that you can access using Google Calendar
- Manage your photos and videos
- Create, edit, organise and delete all your tasks

I would like to add a Google Calendar to the Calendar GNOME app without giving GNOME all of these permissions (only the calendar permissions). How do I do that?

Comment: I have created a new issue: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-calendar/-/issues/1150 Please log in and up-vote to promote this. (The existing issue was rejected due to wording)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to add a Google Calendar to your Calendar GNOME app, without giving all these permissions. However, this method only lets you read your Google Calendar and not make modifications to it through the Calendar GNOME app.

1. Open https://calendar.google.com
2. Open the calendar settings for a particular calendar in Google Calendar's web interface
3. Scroll down until you find the setting labelled "Secret address in iCal format". Copy that address.
4. Open Calendar, the GNOME app
5. Click the calendar icon, and click "Manage calendars..."
6. Click "Add calendar..."
7. Paste the address of the calendar under "Import a calendar", and click "Add".